# How to override cms-full-width.xml in Magento 2.4..3-p1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1

In my Magento 2.4.3-p1 I want to change the layout of the CMS pages to be same as product page. Currently the CMS page contents are shown in full width. It is adding the class `page-main-full-width` to the `maincontent` tag. This is added from the file `vendor\magento\module-page-builder\view\frontend\page_layout\cms-full-width.xml`. How can I override this file in my theme. I have tried `luma_custom/Magento_Page_Builder/page_layout/cms-full-width.xml` but is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copy file in below path:**

Replace **Vendor_name & custome_theme_name** from path with your vendor and theme name

**Create :** cms-full-width.xml

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/custome_theme_name/Magento_PageBuilder/page_layout/cms-full-width.xml
```

Then flush the cache it will work for you